# Append an array of objects into an HTML file

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, append

I have an array of objects that I am mapping through. I would like to append it into an unordered-list in my html file. This what I am currently trying to do. I am getting this error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null".

```
var newWorkArray= works.map(function(work){
return {
    name : work.name,
    title : work.title,
    pic : work.pic,
    link : work.link,
    github : work.github
};


});
console.log("newArray", newWorkArray);

const workLiTag= document.createElement("li")
const workItem= document.createTextNode(newWorkArray)
workLiTag.appendChild(workItem)
document.getElementById("#work-items").appendChild(workItem)
```

I dont think its needed but I'll add the array of objects

```
 var works = [
{
  name:"Lorem Ipsum",
  title: "Lorem Ipsum",
  pic: "Lorem Ipsum",
  link: "Lorem Ipsum",
  github:"Lorem Ipsum"
},

{
 name:"Ruby on Rails | Vue",
 title: "Project Manager",
 pic: "Lorem Ipsum",
 link:"Lorem Ipsum",
 github:"Lorem Ipsum"
 },
```

Comment: `getElementById("#work-items")` should not contain `#`. There is no element with an ID equal to `"#work-items"` so `getElementById` returns `null`

Comment: ... BTW, `document.createTextNode(newWorkArray)` will result in this text node: `"[[objectObject],[objectObject],...]"`, use `JSON.stringify` or construct DOM elements for each property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to loop through your newly mapped array. And even if you didn't, `.getElementById` accepts the id of your target element itself, not a selector similar to `.querySelector`. I used the latter instead. `.createTextNode` attempts to create a text of a javascript object, which is wrong, you need to stringify the object first using `JSON.stringify` if you really need to display the entire object as a text.

```js
var works = [
{
  name:"Lorem Ipsum",
  title: "Lorem Ipsum",
  pic: "Lorem Ipsum",
  link: "Lorem Ipsum",
  github:"Lorem Ipsum"
},
{
  name:"Ruby on Rails | Vue",
  title: "Project Manager",
  pic: "Lorem Ipsum",
  link:"Lorem Ipsum",
  github:"Lorem Ipsum"
}
];

var newWorkArray = works.map(function(work){
   return {
     name : work.name,
     title : work.title,
     pic : work.pic,
     link : work.link,
     github : work.github
   };
});

newWorkArray.forEach(function(i){
  const workLiTag = document.createElement("li");
  workLiTag.textContent = JSON.stringify(i);
  document.querySelector("#work-items").appendChild(workLiTag);
})
```

```html
<ul id="work-items"></ul>
```

I also do not understand why you have to map the original array if the output is literally the same. But I'm just gonna assume you left that detail in order to make the question more straightforward. Otherwise, I would forget about creating a new array using `.map()` since you're not really doing anything.

Comment: Youre right, I dont know why I was mapping through it. Thanks. I still get this error though Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.  Even after I changed everything.

Comment: @JonathanVBritannia You need to inspect your changes more closely since my snippet works without errors. You can try running the snippet. Or is there something else that we have missed that isn't included in your question? You can try wrapping the javascript under `window.onload = function(){}` just to make sure the html is properly loaded before appending anything to it. Or just put the scripts at the bottom